# How to force detectMultiScale search on 1:1 scale?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

How to force OpenCV [CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) function search only on 1:1 scale?

How many scales used by default?

**UPD:**
Found relate code:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/cc92cd07e8d6a54dfd57d5f74c3d4e05b1d956af/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp

```
for( double factor = 1; ; factor *= scaleFactor )
{
Size originalWindowSize = getOriginalWindowSize();

Size windowSize( cvRound(originalWindowSize.width*factor), cvRound(originalWindowSize.height*factor) );
if( windowSize.width > maxObjectSize.width || windowSize.height > maxObjectSize.height ||
windowSize.width > imgsz.width || windowSize.height > imgsz.height )
break;
if( windowSize.width < minObjectSize.width || windowSize.height < minObjectSize.height )
continue;
scales.push_back((float)factor);
}
```

Comment: you can set a maximum size. by default the min size (depends on trained data) is increased by scalefactor until it doesnt fit inside the image anymorw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of scales used in `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` depends on image size, original trained window size, `minObjectSize`, `maxObjectSize` and `scaleFactor` parameters. It loops through all the scales starting with 1 in increments of `scaleFactor` until one of the conditions:

- current window size is larger image size
- current window size is larger maxObjectSize

So there are several possibilities to reduce number of scales used in `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale:

1. Set `maxObjectSize` parameter equal to original trained size. It guaranties that cascade will use only 1:1 scale.
2. Set `scaleFactor` parameter to extremely large value (1000 for example). Thus next scale after 1 will not be used since window size is much larger than image size. It's dirty hack as for me.

Please be sure that you tune `minNeighbors` parameter. If you would use only one scale you will get very few candidates, so to detect something you need you must decrease this parameter.

Comment: Alternatively you can set `minObjectSize` and `maxObjectSize` to the same value.